# How to install Anaconda python for multiple or all users?

Tags: macos, user-account, python

How to install https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual not just for Administrator?
I was trying to install it from GUI but installation for all users was disabled:

[image]

Comment: Are the different users on the same machine? Or are you running from a server?

Comment: @jmh different (non admin) for same macbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make **Anaconda** available to all **Users** from the [**Individual Edition**](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), using the, e.g. **Anaconda3-2020.07-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg** *package* from the download link at the bottom of the linked web page, e.g. **64-Bit Graphical Installer (462 MB)**, then do the following:

From an **Admin** account...

1. Download e.g.: **Anaconda3-2020.07-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg**
2. Install it to: **/Users/Shared**

   - Select **Install on a specific disk...** and navigate to **/Users/Shared** on the **Macintosh HD**.

After the **GUI** install...

3. For the **User** doing the original install of **Anaconda**, if `bash` is your *default shell* you should be set because the **GUI** *installer* sets up what's necessary in `~/.bash_profile`, however, if `zsh` is your *default shell*, run the following *commands*<sup>1</sup> in **Terminal**:

   - **Note:** For each additional **User**, steps 3 thru 5 are required regardless of your *default shell*.
   - <sup>1</sup> For each additional **User** setting up, if `bash` is your *default shell* just use `conda init` in step 3.

     ```
     source /Users/Shared/anaconda3/bin/activate
     conda init zsh
     ```
   - For `zsh` the `~/.zshrc` *file* is created or written to in this step.
4. Close the current **Terminal** *window* and open another.
5. To control whether or not each shell session has the base environment activated or not, run `conda config --set auto_activate_base False or True`. To run conda from anywhere without having the base environment activated by default, use `conda config --set auto_activate_base False`. This only works if you have run `conda init` or `conda init zsh` first.

---

With that done, each **User** only has to run steps 3 thru 5 from **Terminal** when logged into their account to have access to what was installed by the **Admin** from the original **GUI** install of **Anaconda**.

Comment: Recent versions have improved and write to both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshrc` (if available). Not sure about steps 4 & 5 (had only 1 account on my Mac).